# Azure databricks snowflakes connector options in python

Tags: python, dataframe, adb

I am trying to write a dataframe to snowflakes using ADB. For that we need to use the options in snowflakes such as `continue on_error` and column mapping. Can any one can give me an example column mapping and on_error continue in Python?

I mean example connection code option in Python